# Magnolia auto release

Tags: content-management-system, magnolia

I'm using Magnolia CMS and after activation, automatic release happens after some time, with the help of superuser and not any of the users by which the activation has been done.

I would like to stop this.

Superuser account isn't used by anyone.

I am able to see release items in inbox on one node and not on the other with the same type of configuration.

There are no logs generated for the auto release.

There are no jobs scheduled in the scheduler.

Magnolia version 4.5

Could I please get some help.

Thank you.

Comment: I still don't get what you actually want to achieve. Can you describe it please?

Comment: I don't understand how it is happening, I want to stop the auto release.

Comment: Auto release of what?

Comment: All the items that have been activated in the inbox. Like every item after a certain amount of time gets released individually, not altogether.

Comment: most likely something configured in workflow. 4.5 is quite old and no longer supported. Workflow config there lived in XML file and had to be uploaded to special location. But can't remember where. sry. Is that EE version or CE?

Comment: It's the CE version, on reading the docs, I looked at the activation flow and config, even the one present in admin central, apart from that I've had a look the scheduler, but couldn't find anything